# How to increase batchSize for MongoDB's ReactiveCrudRepository?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-webflux, project-reactor, batchsize

My when calling my mongoDB, my application returns a several hundred "getMore" requests. The batch size is currently 24, and i'd like to increase it in order to minimize the number of expensive calls. Is there a way to configure batchSize for ReactiveMongo?

Note:
I've seen `@Meta(batchSize = [xyz])` been suggested, but only for the standard (nonReactive) `CrudRepository`.

```
public interface TitleReactiveRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Title, String> {

    @Query("{ 'Item' : { '$in': ?0 }, 'hidden' : {'$ne': true } }")
    Flux<Title> findByItem(List<String> TitleId);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/575/commits/49c3d2d48b9ae11e982d2a52e0eeac54d680173f) pull request you use the annotation:

```
@Meta(cursorBatchSize = 100)
```

And this seems to apply to reactive also according to the [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/575)