# Slow get operations with spring webflux + mongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-webflux

```
I have an API where I have a Ticket entity, and the endpoint to get all the tickets is taking like 25 seconds, but in the mongo db there are only 300 tickets.
```

The ticket entity:

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "tickets")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TicketData {

    @Id
    private String ticketId= UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0,10);
    @NotBlank(message="WalletId is required")
    private String walletId;
    @NotBlank(message="RaffleId is required")
    @Indexed(name="raffleIdIndex")
    private String raffleId;
    @NotNull(message="A price is required")
    private Double price;
    private Boolean isWinner;
    private LocalDateTime lastBoughtAt;
}
```

I am using the reactive mongo repository:

```
public interface MongoDBRepositoryTicket extends ReactiveMongoRepository<TicketData, String> {

    Flux<TicketData> findByRaffleId(String raffleId);

}
```

And since i'm trying to do it with a clean architecture approach, this is the adapter method to use the repository:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MongoRepositoryAdapterTicket implements TicketRepositoryGateway {

    private final MongoDBRepositoryTicket ticketRepository;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public Flux<Ticket> getAllTickets() {
        return this.ticketRepository
                .findAll()
                .map(ticket -> mapper.map(ticket, Ticket.class));
    }
```

I also tried to get tickets by raffleId and indexing this raffleId attribute, but it didn't improve. When printing the db operations with:

`logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core = DEBUG`

It shows that the application is really slow running the onAfterLoad and onAfterConvert for each document, with these kind of logs:

```
2023-05-30 11:50:19,699        DEBUG [nioEventLoopGroup-3-7] ent.AbstractMongoEventListener: onAfterLoad({ "_id" : "25c2370a-4", "walletId" : "khds3", "raffleId" : "597e7098-7", "price" : 5.0, "isWinner" : false, "lastBoughtAt" : { "$date" : "2023-05-25T23:33:30.411Z"}, "_class" : "io.rottenville.ticket.infrastructure.drivenadaptrs.data.TicketData"})

2023-05-30 11:50:19,699        DEBUG [nioEventLoopGroup-3-7] ent.AbstractMongoEventListener: onAfterConvert({ "_id" : "25c2370a-4", "walletId" : "khds3", "raffleId" : "597e7098-7", "price" : 5.0, "isWinner" : false, "lastBoughtAt" : { "$date" : "2023-05-25T23:33:30.411Z"}, "_class" : "io.rottenville.ticket.infrastructure.drivenadaptrs.data.TicketData"}, { "$java" : TicketData(ticketId=25c2370a-4, walletId=khds3, raffleId=597e7098-7, price=5.0, isWinner=false, lastBoughtAt=2023-05-25T18:33:30.411) })
```

Any thoughts or ideas are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest doing following changes to debug the problem.

1. `findAll()` will use default batch size. With latest version, I am seeing the default batch size of two. This means the Mongo client will make roughly 150 calls to Mongo to fetch all 300 documents. You can search for settings to change default size.
2. With change in default size, it should not result in 25 seconds. So we can debug in steps. First, remove the mapper code and simply subscribe to `getAllTickets` to see how long it takes for repository to get all records and do nothing over it. You can enable `org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command` to `DEBUG`, to see queries getting fired from client and when responses come back.

If you see that responses to `org.mongodb.driver.protocol` class itself is slow then it has nothing to do with code but time it is taking to get the results (you should see similar behavior in any other client).

Can you try these and confirm back?

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thank you for your help. I think you are right, the logs are showing a batch of 2 documents, however I'm having a hard time trying to change that configuration, but it is a good clue. The command that worked for me to get the batch info is:

logging.level.org.mongodb.driver=DEBUG , it is the verbose one.

I've also tried without doing the mapper part and it didn't improve, so if you know how to change the default batch size, it would be great, thank you in advance!

Comment: It worked Gaurav, thank you so much!, 

It worked with the solution provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60108931/how-to-increase-batchsize-for-mongodbs-reactivecrudrepository ,

adding this annotation to the method in the repository: @Meta(cursorBatchSize = 100)

Comment: I have been in the same situation and trying dig dipper and found the same. Now after reading @Gaurav Bhatia explanation I could fix the issue. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As Gaurav said, I think the problem was the default batch size as it was set to 2. Now changing it to 100, the query takes less than a second for 300 documents.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60108931/how-to-increase-batchsize-for-mongodbs-reactivecrudrepository) there is a solution for that, by adding the following annotation to the repository methods:

`@Meta(cursorBatchSize = 100)`